# NoneType Error when using Beautiful Soup object inside function

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Why is it that the penultimate line of this snippet completes successfully, but the last one gives the error: `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`? What is different inside the scope of the function, and how can it be fixed?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def findDiv(soup):
    print soup.body.FindAll("div")

r = requests.get("http://google.com")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
print soup.findAll("div")
findDiv(soup)
```

Comment: Seems you try comparing apples to oranges, namely - you expect the same results from `print soup.body.FindAll("div")` and `print soup.findAll("div")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the `FindAll`. It is not a method. Try `findAll` instead with lowercase.

```
def findDiv(soup):
    print soup.body.findAll("div")
```